# How to trigger job when merging from releases/* to master?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

We have 3 main branches: `development`, `releases/xyz` and `master`. This mirrors the flow from development through release candidates to production.

I want to trigger a job only when a merge request is made from `releases/*` to `master`. I need to block all other merge requests to `master` e.g. to prevent a merge directly from `development` to `master`.

Does Gitlab CI support a trigger ONLY when branch is `master` AND the originating branch matches `releases/*` ?

Answer (score 1):

GitLab does not support triggering a pipeline for merge commits only so far. Therefore it does also not support triggering a pipeline only for some merge commits.

There are two ways you might differentiate merge commits from normal commits:

1. Merge commits have multiple parents.
2. Merge commits have a standardized commit message in regular cases.

GitLab does not support filtering based on number of parents nor on the commit message (except for skipping CI with `[skip ci]` or `[ci skip]`).

You could find more information about support filtering options in the documentation for [`only` and `except` options](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-advanced) of GitLab CI/CD Pipeline Configuration.